# Can I use openCV to compare two faces on two different images?

Tags: opencv, image-recognition

I am very new in openCV, I saw it could figure out the face and return a rectangle to indicate the face. I am wondering whether there is anyway for openCV to access two images, with which contains one face, and I expect openCV to return the possibility of whether those two people are the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV does not provide a full face recognition engine.
You might want to check out this work: [The One-Shot Similarity Kernel](http://www.openu.ac.il/home/hassner/projects/Ossk/) which proposes something similar to what you need. It also provides Matlab code.